# R Shiny using navbarPage and DataTable -

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to rendering the data table in Shiny using "DT" option in R. But, not sure, what is wrong with the patch. Tried everything but "the table is not getting displayed on the page". Any help appreciated.

Below is the code for that page -

```
navbarMenu("Data Tracker", icon = icon("database"),

       tabPanel("A", fluid = TRUE,
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                               
                               dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",
                                              start = "2000-01-01",
                                              end   = "2010-12-31"),
                               
                               #### Time Frame and Data Type Selector
                               
                               selectInput(inputId = "TimeFrame",
                                           choices = c("1","2"),
                                           selected = "1",
                                           width = "220px")
                  ),
                  
                  fluidRow(
                    column(12,
                           box(
                             title = "Data Secription - ", 
                             closable = TRUE,
                             width = 12,
                             status = "primary", 
                             solidHeader = TRUE, 
                             collapsible = TRUE,
                             p("Box Content")
                           ),
                           valueBox(10 * 2, "D"),
                           valueBox(10 * 2, "E"),
                           valueBox(10 * 2, "F?"),
                    ))),
                
                mainPanel(width = 12,
                          DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
                ))
```

Comment: Hard to say because you aren't showing the full code. Did you load DT using `library(DT)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have loaded the required packages.

Comment: Did you code the table in the server.R file and named it "table1"?

Comment: Yes.  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
             DT::datatable("QC_Data") 
           })

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (i.e. the complete code for a running shiny app that shows your problem), then it's easier to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Why is QC_Data in quotes?